# Fade an element in on load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, fade

I'm trying to fade in an element in jQuery and despite its simplicity, it isn't working for me. Here's the code:

```
<table><tr><td>Blah</td></tr></table>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").css('color','green');
    $("table").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

And here's an example in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/heUkN/1/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't fade in unless it's hidden first. Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table").css('color','green');
    $("table").hide().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

Here I've used [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heUkN/5/)

---

You could, alternatively, not display using CSS:

```
table{display: none;}
```

The downfall with this being that, if the user doesn't have JavaScript enabled (unlikely, I know, but possible) the table would never be displayed.

Answer (score 4):

You must `hide()` before you can `fadeIn()`, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("table").css('color','green').hide().fadeIn(2000); 

});
```

Answer (score 3):

Your table is visible by default, use styling to hide it:

```
table {
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/heUkN/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You code is right just to see fadeIn() effect first fadeOut it or hide it like this..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       $("table").fadeOut();
       $("table").css('color','green');
        $("table").fadeIn(2000);
        });
```